# Count number of occurrence of string in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column, which has data like this :-

```
C29,C22,C345
C292,C345,C456
C456,C29,C453
```

Now I want to find number of occurrence of C29, and I am using this formula now:-

```
COUNTIF(I9:I11,"*C29*")
```

But it is returning 3, as it also take C292 in an account, how can I set a formula to match only C29?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

[image]

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(",C29,",","&A1:A3&",")))
```

Or, less verbose:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A3,"\bC29\b"))
```

Or, even less verbose:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(A1:A3,",")="C29")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, two options:

1. use sum(), if() and iferror() with find() as shown down in rows 11 to 13, formula is:

   =SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND("C29,",A11:A13,1),0)>0,1,0))
2. if you have the room, the do Text-to-Columns and get each data element into its own cell. Then extract the numbers, either replace the C with nothing or mid() as shown. Then count the 29.

[image]